# Getting next value from typed

Tags: r

I have six cards in following order: 9,8,5,10,2,6
I want to write a code that will give me next value from the list and when typed the last will back to the begining again.

I tried to do it with "2" (wanting to get "6" as result) and wrote:

```
cards <- c(9,8,5,10,2,6)
o <- 1:6
if(karty[o] == 2) cat(karty[o+1])
```

However it's not working at all :/ Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You want an endless loop?

Comment: Use `cards[o%%6]` to get it to wrap around.  This is the modulus.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cards_fun <- function(val){
  if (val %in% cards[1:(length(cards)-1)]) ind = which(cards==val)+1 else if (val %in% cards[length(cards)]) ind = 1
  cards[ind]
}
cards_fun(9)
cards_fun(6)
```

Really like the modulus suggestion in the comment above if you'd like to use that instead

```
cards_fun2 <- function(val){
 o <- 1:length(cards); cards[(o%%length(cards))[cards %in% val]+1]
}
cards_fun2(9)
cards_fun2(6)
```